# Scala multimap: get item or else empty set

Tags: scala, multimap

if I'm using the Scala Multimap, and I want to get the values associated with a key or else the empty set, do I have to write the following?

```
multimap.getOrElse("key", new collection.mutable.HashSet())
```

It would seem that the following should just work.  An empty set seems like a good default value.

```
multimap.getOrElse("key")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you observed, the `MultiMap` trait doesn't do what you want. However, you can add a default value yourself if the Map is specifically mutable or immutable. Here's an example,

```
scala> val m = collection.mutable.Map(1 -> 2)
m: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2)

scala> val m2 = m.withDefaultValue(42)
m2: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2)

scala> m2(1)
res0: Int = 2

scala> m2(2)
res1: Int = 42
```

Strangely, the above won't work if the type of `m` is an abstract `collection.Map`. The comment in the source code says this is due to variance issues.

Comment: Hmmm... it would be great if getOrElse(key) were added!

Answer (score 4):

Normally you would use `Map.withDefaultValue` for this. However, it looks as if you can't really get this behavior and still have a collection typed as a `MultiMap[A, B]`. The return type of `MultiMap.withDefaultValue` is `Map[A, Set[B]]`.  So unfortunately you'll have to abandon the use of the MultiMap mixin to get the behavior you desire.

Answer (score 0):

The `withDefaultValue` can be use for this use case. For instance:

```
import collection.mutable._
val multimap = Map[String, HashSet[String]]() withDefaultValue(new HashSet())
scala> multimap("key")
// res1: scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[String] = Set()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as expected. `multimap("key") += "value"` doesn't modify the map. I'm guessing default values aren't cached.

Answer (score 0):

Since, as [Garrett Rowe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/273115/garrett-rowe) [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6961573/455009), `withDefaultValue` doesn't preserve the proper `MultiMap` type when using the mixin, you can instead override the `default` method in an anonymous class and preserve the behavior of `MultiMap`:

```
scala> import collection.mutable.{ HashMap, MultiMap, Set }
import collection.mutable.{HashMap, MultiMap, Set}

scala> val map: MultiMap[String, Int] = new HashMap[String, Set[Int]] with MultiMap[String, Int] {
     |   override def default(key: String): Set[Int] = Set.empty[Int]
     | }
map: scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap[String,Int] = Map()

scala> map("foo")
res0: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set()

scala> map.addBinding("foo", 1)
res1: map.type = Map(foo -> Set(1))

scala> map("foo")
res2: scala.collection.mutable.Set[Int] = Set(1)
```